# C++ Graphic API with a small learning curve - linux

Tags: c++, linux, graphics

i have to do some very basic drawing in Linux , like joining some points , tracing trajectory of a moving point . I am looking for a graphic library which has a very small learning curve so that i can save my time and avoid getting into things like gtk and opengl since i don't need something complicated .

---

Edit 1 :Can you provide links to the tutorials for SDL which explains very basic drawing also for any other libraries which you think is relevant .

Comment: Like art in the real world, art on a computer also has a steep learning curve. GTK is probably about as simple as you can expect to get.

Comment: If you just want to draw lines and plot points, I find SDL is a pretty simple tool. It is very powerful and has lots of features, but if you stick to the simple drawing stuff you can get going pretty quickly.

Comment: I found allegro pretty easy to learn too, but SDL is probably a better choice.

Comment: While Qt is indeed big, it has a good documentation and you could learn only the parts interesting you (QGraphicsScene probably).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [pygame](http://www.pygame.org), [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/), or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) with [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/). All of these are available through the most popular package repositories.

Be prepared to get used to dealing with surfaces, graphics primitives, blitting, and the like. The learning curve is not large, but it's still a significant paradigm shift if you've never done graphics before.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught with [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/), and as the middle aged man says "I turned out OK didn't I?"

Answer (score 0):

You might be also interested in [Cocos2dx](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/), it works on [many different platforms](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki) (linux included).